# Fetch value of selection field instead of key

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I defined a `selection` field in one model.

```
type = fields.Selection([('a','A'),('b','B'),('c','C')])
```

In one of function i tried to get `string value` instead of `key`.

```
@api.multi
    def testFunc(self):
    for res in self:
        print'Value',res.type //It prints 'a'.
```

I need to print 'A'.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose One of the solutions :

The most importing thing that you can get the selection list like this:

```
    self._fields['type'].selection
```

So try this:

```
    # convert the list to dictionary
    dict(self._fields['type'].selection).get(self.type)
```

IF you want the label to be translated in user language:

```
  # here the label return is translated.
  value = dict(self.fields['state']._description_selection(self.evn)).get(self.type)
```

Comment: Hello Cherif. For odoo10 your solution not work for me. Please suggest me, how to solve this?

Comment: Take a look at fields.py and see how to retrieve the value from there but what exactly didn't work what error did you have

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method, it returns the string value, translated if it's the case:

```
@api.multi
    def testFunc(self):
    for res in self:
        print'Value', dict(res.fields_get(["type"],['selection'])['type']["selection"]).get(res.type)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible and simple solution would be:

```
VALUES_TYPE = [('a','A'),('b','B'),('c','C')]

type = fields.Selection(VALUES_TYPE )

dict(VALUES_TYPE )[self.type]
```